# How to insert 3.5k ints to array in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have custom type:

```
create or replace type integer_varray as varray (4000) of int;
```

Then table which uses this array:

```
create table plan_capacities
(
  id       int generated by default as identity not null constraint plan_capacities_pkey primary key,
  line_id  int references lines (id) on delete cascade,
  model_id int references models (id) on delete cascade,
  plan_id  int references plans (id) on delete cascade,
  capacity integer_varray
);
```

And then some data I would like to insert in. The problem is that in Oracle I can't use more than 1000 items (I have 3 500 items) in the array "constructor" so simple statement

```
INSERT INTO plan_capacities ("model_id", "line_id", "plan_id", "capacity") VALUES (1,1,1,integer_varray(1,2,3.....35000))
```

Is not possible to use. (data are some capacities and the have to be in the specific order).

Data that should be inserted into array are in a string I have to put into script. -> `{1,10,11,10,20,0,0,0,1,10 ....}`

How can I insert that load of data?

I tried to insert them into temp table and then filling array with them - this works but that sql script has 3500 rows (to create just one records to `plan_capacities`) which is awful and big.

Comment: I don't really know but maybe you could create a CSV and then load your data from that CSV ? (by using SQL*Loader)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my final solution is following:

```
create or replace type integer_varray as varray (4000) of int;
/

create or replace type varchar_varray as varray (10) of varchar(32767);
/

declare
  data_to_be_stored varchar_varray := varchar_varray(
    '0,0,0,0,.....',
    '0,0,0,0,0,0....',
    '0,0,0,0,0,0....'
  );
  array_to_store    integer_varray := integer_varray();
begin
  for i in 1 .. data_to_be_stored.COUNT loop
    for j in (select to_number(trim(regexp_substr(data_to_be_stored(i), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))) value
              from dual
              connect by LEVEL <= regexp_count(data_to_be_stored(i), ',') + 1
    ) loop
      array_to_store.extend;
      array_to_store(array_to_store.count) := j.value;
    end loop;
  end loop;
  insert into table_with_that_array (array) values (array_to_store);
end;
\
```

I had to you use `varchar_varray`because my data/strings are bigger than max capacity of `varchar2`so I split it into multiple strings in array.

Answer (score 3):

You can use your array as a table to insert its values into a table with a single SQL statement; for example:

```
declare
    vArray integer_varray;
begin
    -- some code to populate vArray

    insert into someTable(col)
    select column_value from table(vArray);
end;
```

If you can populate your array with a query, you don't need the array, simply using your query as a data source for the insert statement; for example:

```
insert into someTable(col)
select something
from someOtherTable
```

If you need a way to create a set of numbers, say 1, 2, ... 3500, this is a commonly used way:

```
select level 
from dual 
connect by level <= 3500
```

About a way to build a set of numbers from a string, this is a quite usual way:

```
SQL> create or replace type integer_varray as varray (4000) of int
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create table someTable(n number);

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2      vString     varchar2(32000) := '1,10,11,10,20,0,0,0,1,10';
  3      vArray      integer_varray;
  4  begin
  5      insert into someTable(n)
  6      select to_number(regexp_substr(vString, '[^,]+', 1, level))
  7      from dual
  8      connect by instr(vString, ',', 1, level - 1) > 0;
  9  end;
 10  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from someTable;

         N
----------
         1
        10
        11
        10
        20
         0
         0
         0
         1
        10

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: This is something what I'm already doing - problem is how to populate array or temp table with that amount of data.

Comment: It's not that clear to me. Don't you have your data stored somewhere? Do you need a way to create data like 1, 2, ... 3500?

Comment: No, I have data for example in string I have to manually insert into sql script.

Comment: Please edit your question by adding some informations to replicate you case.